# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyModbusTCP'

Tags: linux, python, raspberry-pi, tcp, systemd

I am trying to run a python file on bootup which will collect some data from another device.

I created a service in the /etc/systemd/system directory

```
[Unit]
Description = File which requests data from Device
After = multi-user.target

[Service]
Type = simple
ExecStart = /usr/bin/python3 /home/user/file1.py
Restart = always
StartLimitInterval = 60
StartLimitBurst = 10

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

however I get the following error when examining why service didn't start

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyModbusTCP'
```

Based on some other solution I found online it was suggested to remove the package from the user and instead install it in the root directory. So I uninstalled it and installed it via

```
sudo pip3 install pyModbusTCP
```

However it is still the same error. Must I point to the library in the service setup file? Thank you!

Comment: How does `file1.py` include the library? Could you share relevant parts of that script?